# The Color expression... contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: reporting-services

I've added what should be a fairly simple expression to many of my text boxes so that they will display in red when the value is negative. The expression that I'm using is:

```
=Iif(Me.Value < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

It seems to work just fine in some of the text boxes, but in others I get the warning text in the question title and they just display as the default.

I've checked that the text boxes have the same number formatting and I've double checked that the expression is identical between text boxes that work and those that give the warning message.

Is there something else that I can check? Has anyone else run into this? Any other thoughts on how I might correct it or at least debug it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the actual data that cannot be converted to a numeric value (null, blank, alpha-numeric data perhaps). Try testing the value first.

Something like

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Me.Value),IIF(Me.Value < 0, "Red", "Black"), "Blue")
```

I've set "Blue" if the value is not numeric but obviously you can change that to what you like, it might help debug values that look numeric even though they are not such as a number with a leading or trailing space.

Comment: That one hadn't occurred to me. I'll adjust the expression to handle NULL values (since I'm certain that there are some) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: then don't forget null is `nothing` in SSRS expression

Comment: Yep. I've tried several variants of the above and with IsNothing and haven't found one that works yet. Is there any way to effectively "trace" through the expression to see values or otherwise debug a report? (new to SSRS)

Comment: have you tried `VAL` such as `IIF(VAL(Me.Value) < 0, "Red", "Black")` . `VAL` just returns the numeric part as a number. Not tested but in theory this will strip out leading trailing spaces and anything where its null or blank should return 0.

Comment: I assumed that the value of the cell was independent of how it was displayed and that was my mistake. I had it using formatting of a percentage, but that made the actual value a string with a percentage sign. I used LEFT(Me.Value, LEN(Me.Value) - 1) in the IIF statement and that did the trick. Thanks for your help in getting me there!

Comment: You're welcome. FYI: If that was your real code then you are referencing the cell itself, after it's been rendered. If you want to evaluate the actual data then you would reference it from the dataset e.g. Fields!MyField.Value